# How do I make two <pre> tag become same size?

Tags: html, css, tags, pre

Here are my code:

```
table += '<tr>';
table += '<td width="800px" style="vertical-align:top"><pre>' + rqParam + '</pre></td>';
table += '<td width="800px" style="vertical-align:top"><pre>' + resParam + '</pre></td>';
table += '</tr>';
```

I use the variable table to generate a table that I want as
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhSNA.png).

It seems that pre size will depend on the value inside, but what I want is to make the smaller one sized to be the same as the larger one.

Could you guys suggest me which style do I need to use to make it same size dynamically?

Comment: you should provide `width` to `pre` as well.

Comment: pre should be alway same size as td right?

Comment: There is no CSS that can make an element in one TD have the same height as an element in another TD. However, you can apply `font-family: monospace; white-space:pre` to the TDs themselves and then you can dispense with the pre elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a table, it can be easily solved using Flex elements. The following code shows a working sample - I've added a border around the `pre` elements to make it clear that they're the same size.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: center; align-content: center; align-items: stretch;">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1;">
      <pre style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%;">test string</pre>
    </div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
      <pre style="border: 1px solid red; width: 100%;">test string<br>test string<br>test string</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```